# Return Multiple Items in the same row (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm practicing my SQL using the questions here: http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/AdventureWorks_hard_questions

I'm having issues with the first one. I'll repost it here so you don't have to click the link.

> For every customer with a 'Main Office' in Dallas show AddressLine1 of the 'Main Office' and AddressLine1 of the 'Shipping' address - if there is no shipping address leave it blank. Use one row per customer.

The tables involved are CustomerAW (with CustomerID as PKey being I believe the only relevant field), CustomerAddress (with items CustomerID, AddressID, and AddressType), and Address (with AddressID, AddressLine1, and City being the relevant fields).

What I have now is:

```
SELECT A.AddressLine1, 
FROM Address A, CustomerAddress CA, CustomerAW C
WHERE C.CustomerID = CA.CustomerID AND A.City = 'Dallas' AND A.AddressID = CA.AddressID
GROUP BY C.CustomerID
```

but I don't know how to get the shipping address into the second column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There needs to be some sort of field identifying which address in the main address, and which is the shipping.  Assuming you have such a field, then there are a couple different ways to do this.  Here's one with conditional aggregation:

```
select c.customerid,
    max(case when ca.addresstype = 'Main' then a.addressline1 end) as main, 
    max(case when ca.addresstype = 'Ship' then a.addressline1 end) as ship 
from customeraw c  
    join customeraddress ca on c.customerid = ca.customerid
    join address a on ca.addressid = a.addressid
group by c.customerid
having max(case when ca.addresstype = 'Main' then a.city end) = 'Dallas'
```

---

Another option would be to join to the `address` table multiple times -- one for the main office and one for the shipping:

```
select c.customerid,
    a.addressline1 as main,
    a2.addressline1 as ship
from customeraw c  
    join customeraddress ca on c.customerid = ca.customerid
    join address a on ca.addressid = a.addressid and ca.addresstype = 'Main'
    join address a2 on ca.addressid = a2.addressid and ca.addresstype = 'Ship'
where a.City = 'Dallas'
```

With this option, you may need to use an `outer join` for the shipping address depending on the desired results.